# XSLT not working after Sitecore upgrade

Tags: xslt, sitecore, sitecore6

We are using XSLT to show the Sitemap. It was working well until we upgrade our Sitecore from 6.5 to 6.6.
Now we are getting error "Xsl file could not be processed". To check whether we have some issue in logic, we kept an empty XSLT, but we got the same error.
Anyone has idea about this? Or faced the same issue?

**EDIT**:

XSL extensions setting in web.config is:

```
<xslExtensions>
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.XslHelper, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/sc" singleInstance="true" />
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.MainUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/util" singleInstance="true" />
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.DateUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/dateutil" singleInstance="true" />
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentDot, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/dot" singleInstance="true" />
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Xml.Xsl.SqlHelper, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/sql" singleInstance="true" />
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.WebEditRibbon, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/webedit" singleInstance="true" />
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.StringUtil, Sitecore.Kernel" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/stringutil" singleInstance="true" />
</xslExtensions>
```

And log of this error:

```
ERROR Could not resolve type name:
Sitecore.Ecommerce.Classes.XslExtensions,Sitecore.Ecommerce.Custom (method:Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters,Boolean assert)).

ERROR A rendering error occurred: Xsl file could not be processed (details: System.Exception: Could not resolve type name:Sitecore.Ecommerce.Classes.XslExtensions,Sitecore.Ecommerce.Custom (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)). 
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) 
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Assert(Boolean condition, String error) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) 
at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) 
at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.XslFile.ReadXslExtensions() 
at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.XslFile.get_XslExtensions() 
at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.XslFile.AddExtensionObjects(XsltArgumentList list, Item item) 
at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.XslFile.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output, Item item))
```

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate to ask support.sitecore.net

Comment: Have you checked the logs? What's the error in there? Also, usually if you click the little exclamation mark before the 'Xsl file could not be processed' message it'll show you the error in a pop-up.

Comment: As @Trayek says, we need more information about the error. It should be stated on the page and/or in the Sitecore log files.

Comment: Exception says: "System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Ecommerce.Classes.XslExtensions,Sitecore.Ecommerce.Custom(mthod:Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert))."  and then stack trace.

Comment: Do you have that namespace defined in your <xslExtensions> node in the web.config?

Comment: @Trayek Yes, I have this namespace in Web.config

Comment: Did you only upgrade the CMS or did you also upgrade the eCommerce module with it!?

Comment: @Younes Updated CMS only not the eCommerce module.

Comment: A thought: Use the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx tool to determine if your configuration is getting pulled in correctly.  Check the <xslExtensions> node for the appropriate types and classes.

Comment: @PatrickJones Thanks for suggestion, tried the same. But it shows the appropriate settings.

Comment: Can you include the output from showconfig.aspx - just the <xslExtensions> section

Comment: @PaulGeorge Sorry, I don't have any code related to this. The problem was solved for me as we decided to roll back our Sitecore version due to some business constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error above is saying "The XSLT file you've asked me to render refers to an extension class, but I cannot create an instance of that class" - and looking at the config snipped you provided, that doesn't seem to mention the class. As far as I am aware, all XSLT extensions you want to use in your Sitecore Renderings need to be registered before use.

I have not come across the "Sitecore.Ecomerce.Custom" namespace before, but googling it leads me to "Sitecore Ecommerce Fundamental Edition" on SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/SEFE/SEFE11.aspx

Looking through the install package for that, I found a config include file which has the following snippet in it:

```
<xslExtensions>
  <extension mode="on" type="Sitecore.Ecommerce.Classes.XslExtensions,Sitecore.Ecommerce.Custom" namespace="http://www.sitecore.net/ec" singleInstance="true" />
</xslExtensions>
```

(Look at the file "Sitecore.Commerce.Examples.config" in the package for this module)

I suspect your error is related to that line of extra config having been lost from your installation by the upgrade, or perhaps the Sitecore.Ecommerce.Custom.dll binary having been lost?

Putting the missing bits back into your upgraded site may well fix the error.

**However:** The SDN link above suggests that this extension for Sitecore is not compatible with SC 6.6. As I say, I've not used this module before, so I may be missing a newer release hidden in SDN, but the page above says you need v6.3-v6.4 for it to work. I can't tell from my brief google whether Sitecore are saying "This code cannot work with v6.6" or whether they're saying "We've not tested it with v6.6, but it may work - use at your own risk". I'd recommend you check that with Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not test this because we have rolled back our Sitecore version.

Comment: Let me know if this works for anyone, I will mark it as answer so others can get benefit.